# Enable scrolling in x-axis for chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I can't seem to enable a scroll bar on x-axis. I'm using the code below to generate the chart.

```
List<int> xVal = new List<int>();  
List<int> yVal = new List<int>();  
for (int i = 0; i <= maxQueuetime ; i++)  
{  
    xVal.Add(i);  
    yVal.Add(graph2Yaxis[i]);  
}  
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;  
chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";  
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xVal, yVal);
```

[image]

Comment: is this with the winforms mschart controll?

Comment: yes its winform chart control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will let the user drag over a portion of the chart he want to see and then a scrollbar will show up:

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
CA.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

To make the scrollbar show up by code use at least this line:

```
CA.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(firstDataPoint, lastDataPointInView);
```

Depending on your data you may want to set the [`ScaleView.SizeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscaleview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
CA.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
```

I suggest adding a little help to tell the user how to zoom in..

To prevent zooming you can change the default:

```
CA.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
```